# Getting a vector of all unique numerical values in a data.frame

Tags: r, lapply, numeric

I have data as follows:

```
dat <- structure(list(rn = c("region", "lower threshold", "upper threshold"
), east_0_25 = c("east", "0", "25"), north_0_25 = c("north", 
"0", "25")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

                rn east_0_25 north_0_25
1:          region      east      north
2: lower threshold         0          0
3: upper threshold        25         25
```

I am wondering what the easiest way would be to create a vector of all unique numerical values out of this data.frame, **noting that `0` and `25` are character values**.

I guess I could start with:

```
dat <- lapply(dat, as.numeric)
```

To keep only the numerical values. But what should be the next step?

Desired outcome:

```
unique_num_values <- c(0,25)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
x <- unique(as.numeric(unlist(dat)))
unique_num_values <- x[!is.na(x)]
```

Output:

```
[1]  0 25
```

Comment: Swapping the `unique` and `as.numeric` functions would be better - otherwise this would treat `"25"` and `"25.0"` as separate entries.

Comment: Swapped the `unique` and `as.numeric`. Thanks to @AndrewGustar!